# How to pass 'State' from child to parent in 'React Native Functional Component'?

Tags: react-native, state, parent-child, picker

I have created a picker component to get data from API and display it(ProductNames) in the picker list, to select one of them. Then I able to get picker item value as a productID. After that, I use this child component in the parent component, which indicates a form to submit. Now I can see the picker in the parent component(form) and I can select one of them.

My main purpose is to open an input field through the picker. So now I need to pass the item.value ( as a state 'selectedValue')  to parent component to submit. How can I pass this child state to parent state?

this is my child component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';


const ProductPicker = () => {
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');
    const [productDetails, setproductDetails] = useState([]);
console.log('selected value', selectedValue);
    useEffect(() => {
        getProductList();
    }, []);

    const getProductList = async () => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
        

        fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/customer/get-all-products', {

            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authentication': `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => setproductDetails(json.data))
            .catch((error) => console.error(error));

    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Picker
                selectedValue={selectedValue}
                style={{height: 40, width: 150}}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                    setSelectedValue(itemValue);
                }}
            >

     

                {productDetails.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Picker.Item label={item.productName} value={item.productID} key={index}/>);
                })}

            </Picker>

        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 40,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
});

export default ProductPicker;
```

and this is my parent component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Button, View, Text, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {Appbar} from 'react-native-paper';
import {TextInput, HelperText} from 'react-native-paper';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import ProductPicker from './ProductPicker';


const ComplaintSubmission = ({navigation}) => {

    const [productID , setproductID] = useState('');
    const [description , setdescription] = useState('');
    const [token, setToken] = useState('');
    


    const saveToken = async () => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
        console.log('token from storage', token);
        setToken(token);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        saveToken();
        fetch("http://10.0.2.2:3000/customer/lodge-complaint", {

            method: "post",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authentication': `Bearer ${token}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({

                description : description,
            })

        })

    }, []);


    const openAlert = () => {
        Alert.alert(
            "Complaint Successfully Submitted",
            "We review it as soon as possible. Thank you for reaching for us!",
            [{
                text: "OK",
                onPress : () => navigation.navigate("DashboardDrawer" ),

            }]


        );
    }

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Appbar.Header>
        <Appbar.BackAction onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
        <Appbar.Content title="Submit Complaint" />
        <Appbar.Action icon="magnify" onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} />
      </Appbar.Header>
      <Text>Plese Fill the following</Text>
      <View>
         

       <ProductPicker />

        <HelperText type="info">
          Make sure select the correct Product
        </HelperText>
      </View>

      <TextInput
        style={styles.PIDstyle}
        label="Description"
        onChangeText = {(description) => setdescription(description)}
      />
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text>This is submittion</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => openAlert()} title="Submit Complaint" />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
export default ComplaintSubmission;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  PIDstyle: {
    marginTop: 30,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
});
```

Comment: See [Passing Data from Child to Parent with React Hooks](https://dev.to/pnkfluffy/passing-data-from-child-to-parent-with-react-hooks-1ji3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to pass the state from child to parent, you want to pass it from parent to child.  You need to [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to `ComplaintSubmission` and use props to control `ProductPicker`.

In `ComplaintSubmission`, call the `ProductPicker` with the current `productId` and a callback to update it.

```
<ProductPicker productID={productID} setproductID={setproductID} />
```

Now `ProductPicker` has these props.  It should use them instead of the local state `selectedValue` which you can now delete.

```
const ProductPicker = ({productID, setproductID}) => {
```

```
<Picker
    selectedValue={productID}
    style={{height: 40, width: 150}}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
        setproductID(itemValue);
    }}
>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Linda Pasiste. It's really helpful. Appreciate your answer!

Comment: can you confirm is their no any doubt in fetch method. it is not working for me . i added the productId also. but did not successfully sumitted.